# Google Assistant doesn't work with Custom Intents

Tags: android, app-actions

Google assistant doesn't catch the custom intent. I've implemented custom intent and it triggers fine from Test Tool. It works from Test Tool just fine.

But I can't figure out how to register this capability or shortcut in google assistant so it starts resolving the requests.

It works perfectly with BII.

Custom intent(shortcuts.xml):

```
<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <shortcut
        android:shortcutId="GET_STATUS"
        android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/assist_get_status"
        android:enabled="true">
        <capability-binding android:key="custom.actions.intent.GET_STATUS"/>
    </shortcut>

    <capability
        android:name="custom.actions.intent.GET_STATUS"
        app:queryPatterns="@array/assistant_queries_get_status">

        <app-widget
            android:identifier="GET_STATUS_WIDGET"
            android:targetClass="<MY APP ID>.ui.assistant.GetStatusWidgetProvider"
            android:targetPackage=<MY APP ID>
            <extra android:name="hasTts" android:value="true"/>
        </app-widget>

        <intent
            android:identifier="GET_STATUS_FALLBACK"
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetClass="<MY APP ID>.ui.assistant.GetStatusWidgetProvider">
        </intent>
    </capability>
</shortcuts>
```

Query patterns:

```
<string-array name="assistant_queries_get_status">
    <item>(to)? get (my)? status</item>
    <item>(to)? check status</item>
    <item>how is home</item>
    <item>get (my)? sensors statuses</item>
    <item>what is the status (at home)?</item>
    <item>how is the house</item>
    <item>provide (a)? status report</item>
</string-array>
```

In manifest I have:

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".ui.assistant.GetStatusWidgetProvider"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/button_widget" />
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".ui.assistant.GetStatusWidgetProvider"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.assistant.appactions.widgets.PIN_APP_WIDGET" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

And I added shortcuts meta-data to launch activity as well.

The query I tried: "Hey Google, ask TEST APP how is home?" and it doesn't work.

If I change the capability and shortcut to `actions.intent.GET_EXERCISE_OBSERVATION` (and remove queryPatterns of course) and try something like:
"Ask TEST APP, "How many miles have I run today?"." - it works!

I also ran an internal test in GP, logged in the same account in Android Studio as on my test device, the same that I use in GP to publish and internal testing - all the same.
From Test Tool - works, from Assistant - nope.

I can't understand if I missed something or it's a bug.

Any help is highly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Hi, can share what you did to fix this ?

Comment: It's still broken.